# Compiling the tensorflow lite minimal example

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to use tensorflow lite on android. I'm getting an error during compilation with android studio:

```
undefined reference to 'tflite::InterpreterBuilder::operator()(std::__ndk1::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter, std::__ndk1::default_delete<tflite::Interpreter> >*)'
```

I've managed to get a reproducible example while trying to compile [this minimal example from the tf repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/minimal).

Steps to get the error

1. Download the android ndk (I've tried both 15c and 16b and they both failed) . Call `build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py --arch arm --api 21 --stl=libc++ --install-dir android-toolchain`
2. Build libtensorflow, this is in my build file.

`tensorflow/lite/BUILD`

```
cc_binary(
    name = "libtensorflowlite.so",
    linkopts=[
        "-shared",
        "-Wl,-soname=libtensorflowlite.so",
    ],  
    linkshared = 1,
    copts = tflite_copts(),
    deps = [ 
        ":framework",
        "//tensorflow/lite/kernels:builtin_ops",
    ],  
)
```

I call it like:

```
bazel build //tensorflow/lite:libtensorflowlite.so --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool --cpu=armeabi-v7a --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain --cxxopt="-std=c++11"
```

3. I clone the flatbuffer repo (a dependency) and compile it.
4. Then I try and compile `minimal.cc`.

I call it like:

```
android-toolchain/bin/clang++  -std=c++11 -Igit/tensorflow-android -Igit/flatbuffers/include -Lgit/tensorflow-android -Lgit/flatbuffers/build minimal.cc -ltensorflowlite -lflatbuffers
```

(`libtensorflow.so` is in `git/tensorflow-android`, `libflatbuffers.a` in `git/flatbuffers/build`)

What's going on? I have no idea why this method is being called, I'm not calling the object with two arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was me not being on ndk 18. I hadn't switched to it because when compiling bazel was specifically telling me to use <=16!